# Query issue Unknown column status

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do I check status in where clause?

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`start_date`,`end_date`,
CASE
WHEN SYSDATE() <  `start_date` THEN 'WAITING'        
WHEN SYSDATE() >= `start_date` AND SYSDATE() <= `end_date` THEN 'START'
WHEN SYSDATE() >= `end_date`   THEN 'END'
END `status`
FROM teams WHERE `status` = 'START';
```

When I execute this Query they generate an error like this

[image]

See database screenshot also

[image]

Comment: Could you give us a bit more information? what's your table structure?

Comment: Why do you need the CASE statement? Wouldn't a WHERE clause do the same job?

Comment: Does the teams table contain the column "status"? If my table has the field status your query works. see my db setup here: https://gist.github.com/2160968

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you can't reference your computed column by name in the same query. So you need to use an inner sub-query:

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`start_date`,`end_date`, `status`
FROM (
  SELECT `id`,`name`,`start_date`,`end_date`,
    CASE
      WHEN SYSDATE() <  `start_date` THEN 'WAITING'        
      WHEN SYSDATE() >= `start_date` AND SYSDATE() <= `end_date` THEN 'START'
      WHEN SYSDATE() >= `end_date`   THEN 'END'
    END `status`
  FROM teams) AS T
WHERE `status` = 'START';
```

Or you can duplicate the logic in your `WHERE` clause, but most people prefer not to do that. Also note that this solution allows you to simply change your `WHERE` clause to get the other result sets:

- `WHERE status = 'WAITING'`
- `WHERE status = 'END'`

You don't have to mess around with the logic after it's set up this way.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't this do the same thing (I'm SQL Server chap so forgive me if I'm missing something or if the syntax isn't 100%)?

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`start_date`,`end_date`, 'START' AS `status`
FROM Teams 
WHERE SYSDATE() >= `start_date` AND SYSDATE() <= `end_date`
```

Comment: Thanx for sharing your experience

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you are trying to use column that is alias

```
SELECT `id`,`name`,`start_date`,`end_date`,
CASE
WHEN SYSDATE() <  `start_date` THEN 'WAITING'        
WHEN SYSDATE() >= `start_date` AND SYSDATE() <= `end_date` THEN 'START'
WHEN SYSDATE() >= `end_date`   THEN 'END'
END `status`
FROM teams WHERE SYSDATE() between `start_date` and `end_date`;
```

Comment: Thanx for sharing your experience